# Python CSV output

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, web-crawler, export-to-csv

I have piwik response data. I need to output it to csv file. And when i open it, it should be properly formatted in Excel. What i am getting now is a comma separated file in excel and i have to format it every time. Below is my code

```
siteIDs = [51]
#def calculate():
for id in siteIDs:
    for date in daterange(min_date, max_date):
        response_data = {}
        #print date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        token_auth = '35a2c1b4707f45cebfbdaa7f6c3af267'
        url = 'http://survey.modul.ac.at/piwikAnalytics/?module=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&idSite=' + str(id) + '&format=csv&token_auth=' + token_auth + '&period=day&date=' + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&filter_limit=2000'
        #print url
        try:
            response=requests.get(url,timeout=100)
            response_url=response.url
            response_data=urllib.urlopen(url)

        except (requests.exceptions.Timeout,requests.exceptions.RequestException,requests.exceptions.HTTPError,requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,socket.error) as e  :
            response_data="error"
        data = response_data.read()
        with open('raw_csv/piwik_'+ str(id) + '_' + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+ '.csv', 'w') as fp:
             c = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',',lineterminator = '/n')
             #for row in data:
                     #c.writerow([row]) 
             fp.write(data)
```

If i use the last two commented lines, it gives me in the proper format but one character in each cell.
The output i am getting is:
 [image]

And the output i want is:
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `c.writerow(row.split(','))` not `c.writerow([row])`.  The second is writing the entire row in one column.  `writerow` takes an iterable of the column values.  Since `row` is a string, `c.writerow(row)` would iterate over the single characters of the string, so split on comma to get the right kind of list.

Also for writing csv files, use (per csv documentation):

```
open(filename,'wb')           # Python 2.x
open(filename,'w',newline='') # Python 3.x
```

`c = csv.writer(fp)` is sufficent for creating the writer.  The defaults are correct for Excel.

Comment: I implemented this. Now it prints one character in each row f the first column.

Comment: @DigantaBharali Ah, `row` is a single string of data.  You don't really need `csv.writer` if the line is already in a comma-delimited format.  You can `c.writerow(row.split(','))`, though.  I'll update.